# Is there a performance difference between member initializer lists and assignment?

Tags: c++, performance, member-initialization, ctor-initializer

I was recently discussing with a friend and they said there is a performance gain when you use an initialization list to (as opposed to not and simply assigning the data members) when creating objects in C++.

Why is this (if it is true)?

I found this page:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html

and they mention temporary objects but I would have thought recent compilers could avoid this?

Comment: Never mind performance, it's just more correct and appropriate to initialize.

Comment: You're rarely likely to see a difference in performance. Some initialization *must* be done as real initialization though, not as assignment (e.g., references, const objects).

Comment: Initialization is just initialization; assignment is initialization followed by assignment.

Comment: So is there a performance difference? Was this just an old "rule"?

Comment: It depends. You may not notice a performance effect if you're just using a few built-in types as members. With objects that do non-trivial work in the constructor / assignment operator you're likely to notice a difference. It's not just an "old rule" at all. Initializer lists are nearly always the best way to go (and as pointed out above are sometimes the only way to go).

Comment: I honestly use initialization list because i can keep things separated, I haven't noticed a real performance gap between the 2 solution, it's also important to note that a real programmer should not use classes as depot for data and fill them with values and unnecessary things, remember that programs are data structures and algorithms, classes should be more like an expression about what your program will do not what it stores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using assignment, the objects are default constructed before you get to the assignment. If constructing and copying an object are expensive operations, you should at least get rid of one of them. An initialization list gets rid of the additional copying operation. Copy constructing allows to do both at the same time.