# Pass constructor into class

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I'm using LuaBridge and want to pass C++ information into the class.

For example, let's say I have class `A`. Its constructor requires an integer `a`.

```
class A
{
    A(int a){};

    int b;
}
```

I'm using this to create the Lua namespace;

```
luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(L)
    .beginClass<A>("A")
    .addConstructor<void(*)(), RefCountedPtr<A>>()
    .endClass();
```

How do I set class A's constructor this way? I don't want the constructor be modified by Lua.

Comment: anyone willing to help out?

Comment: Why doesn't `.addConstructor <void (*) (int)> ()` work? (Assuming `A::A(int)` is made public and not private as you have it above)

Comment: Because I don't want the user to change the constructor in Lua. Let's say for example the constructor is the renderer, without it the class doesn't know how to render..

Comment: How do you see the user being able to change the constructor in lua? Once you bind the C++ code to it, there isn't a way to just "reassign" a new way on how you construct an object.

Comment: Isn't `.addConstructor` used in Lua, like `foo = Foo(1)`?

Comment: Otherwise, how do I use `.addConstructor` in this way for `int a`?

Comment: yeah, `foo = A(1)` creates a new `A` instance using `A::A(int)` from c++ land. You haven't modified the constructor here nor changed its behavior in any way. eg. `bar = A(42)` will create yet another `A` object referable through `bar` in lua.

Comment: Though I already made it clear I don't want to set the constructor _in Lua_. I want to set the constructor _in C++_. If the constructor is the rendering engine, so that `A` can render to the screen, how do I set the constructor _in C++_?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense. What do you mean *set* a constructor? It isn't something you set, it's a body of code you define(in this case from c++ land binded to lua) that gets called to create and initialize an object.

Comment: Okay, how about if the Renderer, perhaps `sf::RenderWindow` is a public variable of the class `A`. How do I set this, in C++, rather than Lua?

Comment: If `RenderWindow` is a non-static member of `A`, you would just use an initializer list in `A`'s constructor. If it's static then you would initialize it at the global scope, eg. something like `sf::RenderWindow A::m_renderwindow{};` in your .cpp file.

Comment: How do I make initializer lists like this?

Comment: See [Constructors and member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679977/constructor-initialization-vs-assignment and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html

Comment: I mean how do I integrate this with LuaBridge?

Comment: Assuming `RenderWindow` is part of `A` and you want to init it as part of the ctor shown above, it would look like `A(int a) : m_renderwindow() /* default construct RenderWindow */ {}`. You will then have LuaBridge just bind that constructor from my first comment, `.addConstructor <void (*) (int)> ()`.

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere now - though `RenderWindow` was created by another class, so using this method how do I send the engine to `A`?

Comment: You could have another `A` constructor taking a `RenderWindow *` and pass it in like that. You could bind `RenderWindow` as another class and from lua pass that renderwindow instance into `A` on construction. Another way is to have `A` call some singleton constructor of renderwindow and so lua wouldn't need to worry about this at all. It depends on what design you're after.

Comment: How do I do this with a singleton? Sorry for all these questions but I'm really new to working with Lua in C++.

Comment: It means you make a single instance that's accessible globally. Assuming you want to hide the notion of a `RenderWindow` from lua, your `A` from c++ still needs it in order to function. You would initialize the `RenderWindow *` for an `A` object by grabbing the singleton instance and assigning it from one of `A`'s constructors. At this point, this really has more to do with C++ and how you designed the components under the hood rather than lua.