# Instantiating object as a class attribute with custom constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I'm writing a standard game of Battleship using C++, with a Game object that contains two Player objects within it. When I try to instantiate the Player objects in the Game constructor, IntelliSense gives me two errors:

> IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
>
> IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "Player ()" to "Player"

Here's my header file:

```
class Player {
public:
    Player(string name);
    //More unrelated stuff (Get/Set methods and Attributes)
};


class Game {
public:
    Game(bool twoPlayer, string Player1Name, string Player2Name);
    //Get and Set methods (not included)
    //Attributes:
    Player Player1();
    Player Player2();
    int turn;
};
```

My definition of the Player constructor:

```
Player::Player(string name)
{
    SetName(name);
    //Initialize other variables that don't take input
{
```

And the code that's giving the errors:

```
//Game constructor
Game::Game(bool twoPlayer, string Player1Name, string Player2Name)
{
    Player1 = Player(Player1Name);  //These two lines give the first error
    Player2 = Player(Player2Name);
    turn = 1;
}

//Game class Gets
int Game::GetTurn() { return turn; }
Player Game::GetPlayer1() { return Player1; }  //These two lines give the second error
Player Game::GetPlayer2() { return Player2; }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried changing

```
Player1 = Player(Player1Name);
Player2 = Player(Player2Name);
```

to

```
Player1 Player(Player1Name);
Player2 Player(Player2Name);
```

and a number of other things, but nothing works. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `Player Player1();` is a function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the class Game in your header file :

```
class Game {
public:
    Game(bool twoPlayer, string Player1Name, string Player2Name);
    //Get and Set methods (not included)
    //Attributes:
    Player Player1;// 
    Player Player2;//  
    int turn;
};
```

Remove the  parenthesis when declaring your members otherwise you're creating functions called Player1 and Player2 that take no argument

Answer (score 5):

`Player1` and `Player2` are functions. I assume, that you wanted them to be a member variables.

Change `Game` definition to:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game(bool twoPlayer, string Player1Name, string Player2Name);

    //Get and Set methods (not included)

    //Attributes:
    Player Player1;
    Player Player2;
    int turn;
};
```

And use initialization list to initialize your members:

```
Game::Game(bool twoPlayer, string Player1Name, string Player2Name)
: Player1(Player1Name)
, Player2(Player2Name)
, turn(1)
{
}
```

Read more about why you should initialize your members:

- [Constructor initialization vs assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679977/constructor-initialization-vs-assignment)
- [Should my constructors use “initialization lists” or “assignment”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists)

Now, these two lines:

```
Player Game::GetPlayer1() { return Player1; }
Player Game::GetPlayer2() { return Player2; }
```

will not generate any errors anymore.