# Sort stl vector containing template user defined class in decending order using function object

Tags: c++, stl

I am facing an issue while sorting a vector of user defined object. I am using the sort algo defined by stl and passing it my function object but it refuses to compile, would you please help me with this.

Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class MyType
{
    public:
    T t1;
    public:
    MyType()
    {

    }
    MyType(const MyType& mt)
    {
        t1 = mt.t1;
    }
    MyType& operator=(const MyType& mt)
    {
        this->t1 = mt.t1;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator<(const MyType& mt)
    {
        if(this->t1 < mt.t1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    bool operator==(const MyType& mt)
    {
        if(this->t1 == mt.t1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    MyType(T t)
    {
        t1 = t;
    }
};

template<class T>
class cmp_greater
{
    public:
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b)
    {
        return !(a < b);
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyType<int> m1(1);
    MyType<int> m2(2);
    MyType<int> m3(3);

    vector<MyType<int> > vmt;

    vmt.push_back(m1);
    vmt.push_back(m2);
    vmt.push_back(m3);

    vector<MyType<int> >::iterator pos;

    for(pos = vmt.begin(); pos != vmt.end(); pos++)
    {
        cout<<pos->t1<<endl;
    }

    sort(vmt.begin(), vmt.end(), cmp_greater<MyType<int> >() );
    cout<<"After sorting in decending order."<<endl;
    for(pos = vmt.begin(); pos != vmt.end(); pos++)
    {
        cout<<pos->t1<<endl;
    }

    vmt.erase(vmt.begin()+1);

    cout<<"after erase"<<endl;

    for(pos = vmt.begin(); pos != vmt.end(); pos++)
    {
        cout<<pos->t1<<endl;
    }

    //insert can also be used in vectors;
}
```

Comment: Please add the compiler error message to your post by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Your `cmp_greater` is incorrect: if `a` and `b` are equal, it returns `true`. Correct implementation would be `return b < a;`

Comment: I did a quick pass and provided some minor improvements to your code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/516d6e4696ce3fb6 there is still some potential for improvements.

Comment: Just two general remarks, they have nothing to do with your problem: the comparison operators should generally be non-member functions. The MyType constructor should be explicit.

Comment: @Arne Mertz, thanks for the optimizations, would you please provide a link which explains why initialiation should be preferred over assignment in constructors.

Comment: @tan e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679977/constructor-initialization-vs-assignment and here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/17820/,

Answer (score 2):

```
bool operator<(const MyType& mt)
```

It should be declared as `const` like

```
bool operator<(const MyType& mt) const
```

Otherwise, `bool cmp_greater::operator()(const T& a, const T& b)` cannot call the overloaded less-than operator.