# Cout isnt printing string name(No errors are showing)

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, cout

Why this code doesn't print the name? I defined the name in the Animals constructor class,but when i`m running the code it just ignore the definition.

Animal class:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Animals
{
private:

    std::string name;

    std::vector<int> disgust = {1,3,5};
    std::vector <int> sleepTime = { 1,3,5 };
    std::vector <int> childs = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<Animals> theAnimals;

    int disgustBar;
    int sleepBar;
    int animalTotal;

    bool reproduce;

public:
    Animals(std::string name);
    ~Animals();

    void feeding(int i);
    void sleeping(int i);
    void description();
};
```

`Animals.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Animals.h"
#include <iostream>

Animals::Animals(std::string name)
{
    disgustBar = 7;
    sleepBar = 7;
}

Animals::~Animals()
{
}

void Animals::feeding(int i)
{
    disgustBar += i;
    return;
}

void Animals::sleeping(int i)
{
    sleepBar += i;
    return;
}

void Animals::description()
{
    std::cout << "The animal name is " + name  << std::endl;
}
```

Main:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Animals.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Animals a("Allahu");
    a.description();

    return 0;
}
```

(This is my very first post,sorry if i made any kind of mistake)

Comment: Make it a habit to compile with *a lot* more warnings enabled. If you did, you'd have solved this in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot to initialize the `name` member, do this:

```
Animals::Animals(std::string name) 
     : name(name) // <- init name
{
    disgustBar = 7;
    sleepBar = 7;    
}
```

**Suggestion 1:** Initialize all members using the *constructor initialization list*:

```
Animals::Animals(std::string name) 
     : name(name), disgustBar(7), sleepBar(7)
{}
```

Related: [Constructor initialization Vs assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15679977/2020827)

A note about identifier names:

```
   : name(name)
//     ^    ^
//     |    +---- Constructor argument
//     +--------- Class member
```

**Suggestion 2:**
To avoid confusion, I would use a different *attribute name* for the class member.
For example '`name_`' (underscore at the end).

**Suggestion 3:** As mentioned by @Biffen, enable all warnings and do not ignore warnings.

Compiling your code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra` shows the following warning:

> ```
> Animals.cpp:7:1: warning: unused parameter ‘name’ [-Wunused-parameter]
>  Animals::Animals(std::string name)
>  ^
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor needs to initialize the data member `name`:

```
Animals::Animals(std::string n){
    disgustBar = 7;
    sleepBar = 7;
    name = n;
    //---^
}
```

or your constructor could be modified to initialize all the data members, like so:

```
Animals::Animals(std::string n)
   : disgustBar(7), sleepBar(7), name(n) 
{ // body of the constructor }
```

To avoid future similar problems include a function that test the validity of your input (i.e. if all data members are initialized to reasonable values) in the body of the constructor.

---

Note: your data member `animalTotal` may be best declared as `static` and incremented in the body of the constructor (decremented in the body of the destructor), if the intention is to count the number of all the instantiated `Animals` objects.