# c++ error: why this error shows " expected type specifier in vector "

Tags: c++

I include the vector but when I declare a vector inside the class  it shows an error(expected type specifier)
do my code is correct?

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class Ecole {

    vector<string> arr(10);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

As other answers already mentioned, you will need to write the namespace std infront of vector and string.

Also I would assume that you will have to initialise the variable like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> arr = std::vector<std::string>(10);
```

As you cannot initalise it with just `(10)` directly inside of the class. (Outside of a method)

Comment: If you want to avoid the long form initialization (or can't use it because your compiler is out of date), you can use the member initializer list in the constructor. Eg: `std::vector<std::string> arr;` and then `Ecole (): arr(10) { }`. In this case it's a coin-toss as to which is preferable.

Answer (score -2):

The `vector` and `string` are declared in the namespace `std`, So use the namespace to refer them.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class Ecole {

    std::vector<std::string> arr(10);
};
```

If you want to get the rid of using `std` each time, you can write `using namespace std;` before the class declaration;

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Ecole {

    vector<string> arr(10);
};
```

**But this is the bad idea**, see the link [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

The other problem is that you are trying to initialise `arr(10)` the vector without the referring to any variable in the class directly, you have to declare and initialisation both in the class.

```
class Ecole {

    std::vector<std::string> arr = std::vector<std::string>(10);
};
```

And if you want to declare and then initialise in the constructor.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class Ecole {
    
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    
    Ecole(){
        this->arr = std::vector<std::string>(10);
    }
    
};
```

If you want to just play with the vector without the class, you can use directly in the main function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> arr(10);
    // start playing here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The downvote is probably because the initial example does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/eb7bKonsT . For reasons I don't quite understand, that method of initialization was not added when C++ gained the ability to do in-class member initialization.

Comment: `this->arr = std::vector<std::string>(10);` is an assignment that undoes the (admittedly minimal) work that the program already did initializing the `vector` before entering the body of the constructor. Using the member initializer list, `Ecole (): arr(10) { }` is more idiomatic and a possibly a tiny bit more efficient.

Comment: @user4581301 assignment and initialise is not the same meaning with different perspective?

Comment: No. Initialization is done when the variable is defined (or in the member initializer list of a constructor of a class). This invokes the class's constructor. Anywhere else, including in the body of the constructor, you get assignment and invocation of the assignment operator. Outside of the semantics, there are sometimes significant differences between initialization and assignment, and if the initialization is expensive, a subsequent redundant assignment should be avoided.

Comment: Here are a couple questions with good answers that look at the differences in more detail and slightly different ways: [Initialisation and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350155/initialisation-and-assignment) and [Constructor initialization Vs assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679977/constructor-initialization-vs-assignment)

Comment: @user4581301 yes I understand what you are talking about. Compiler will initialise each declaration with the default value or we can give the default value with the `=` assignment operator during the declaration as well.

Answer (score -2):

I bet it would work if you replace `<string>` with `<std::string>` and replace `vector` with `std::vector`

The issue is that `string` and `vector` are included in the `std` namespace, so they must be addressed accordingly.

Another way to make it work is to add

```
using namespace std;
```

...above the `class` declaration, although it is said to be bad practice, as described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/

Comment: Or `using` each of the classes separately, without the whole namespace.

Comment: So `#include <std::string>`?

Comment: No, the `#include` lines are correct as-is.